# Adding Multiple CSV Fields within a singular ListBox

Tags: vb.net, csv, listbox

I've been trying to create a leaderboard a little maze game I'm creating and im using a CSV File to store my data. I have two fields per row, something akin to
James, 20
Luke, 34
Which is "playername" and "score".

Whenever i run the code [below], my listbox displays;

James

20

Luke

34

I'm attempting to display it as something such as

James 20

Luke 34

I've tried to store the first field as a string and grab the next field and concatenate the two together to display it on one line, however i was unable to grab the next field as it would result in a recoding of the reading function.

```
                                FileIO.TextFieldParser(
                                  "C:\Users\zamks1622\Desktop\Computing\SAT\Leaderboard.csv")
            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    Dim currentField As String
                    For Each currentField In currentRow
                        ListLeaderboard.Items.Add(currentField)
                    Next
                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                            FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                    "is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try
            End While
        End Using
```

Comment: Of course that happens. You read a row, which is two fields, and then add an item to the list for each field, which means that you are adding two items per row. If you expect to add one item per row then that's what you need to do. If you expect that item to contain a combination of the fields in the row then you obviously need some code that will combine those fields. I would assume that you have encountered code before that can combine multiple `Strings` into one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
Try
    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
    ListLeaderboard.Items.Add(Join(currentRow , " "))
Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
```